# Using defer attribute in iced-coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

I'm trying to insert a script tag from an iced-coffeescript file. I wish to specify the script's `defer` attribute, but the coffeescript compiler doesn't like that I'm trying to define something called defer, since it's a keyword.

Is there any solution that allows me to do the following:

```
script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.defer = true
script.async = true
script.src = "//initrode.com/scripts/myscript.js"
```

Or am I stuck ande cannot use this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on the [project's GitHub pages](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/111).
You simple have to replace the line with:

```
script["defer"] = true
```